# What is the reason for "elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', '[1:137] unknown field [xlm_roberta]')"?

Tags: elasticsearch, jupyter-notebook

1. What do I want?

   I want to install an additional NLP model to Elasticsearch. The model is called `multilingual-e5-base`.
2. What did I do?

   Therefore, I followed the steps in [Elasticsearch
   documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/machine-learning/current/ml-nlp-import-model.html).
3. What I expected?

   The `multilingual-e5-base` is successfully installed.
4. What I tried?

Here is the relevant section in my Python Notebook for the installation:

```bash
!source ../.env && \
eland_import_hub_model \
    --url ${REMOTE_HOST} \
    --es-username ${USER} \
    --es-password ${API_KEY} \
    --hub-model-id intfloat/multilingual-e5-base \
    --es-model-id multilingual-e5-base \
    --task-type text_embedding \
    --start
```

**Error message:**

```bash
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(meta.status, ApiError)(
elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', '[1:137] unknown field [xlm_roberta]')
```

Comment: What version of ES are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models initialized from xlm-roberta-base, such as [`intfloat/multilingual-e5-base`](https://huggingface.co/intfloat/multilingual-e5-base), are only [supported since version 8.9](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/94089).

The solution is that you **upgrade to at least Elasticsearch 8.9** in order to be able to import this model.

Also, looking at the variable called `${API_KEY}`, it looks like you're using an API key instead of a password. If this is really an API key and not a password, the [authentication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/machine-learning/current/ml-nlp-import-model.html#ml-nlp-authentication) should be done with the `--es-api-key` switch, instead of `--es-username` and `--es-password`.

Comment: The version is: v 8.8.1.

Comment: There you go, upgrade to the latest minor version (8.9) and the error should disappear

Comment: Sure, let me know if that works out

Comment: First I used user/password, now I use the apikey ;-)

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked out!